# Android Dagger: I can't provide an external class without @Inject constructor

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

**EDIT**

**Solved the issue. See my post below.**

I'm writing an Android app with use of Dagger and Kotlin.

I want to inject `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class into my class `DateHelper`

```
@Singleton
class DateHelper @Inject constructor(var dateFormat: SimpleDateFormat) {
...
}
```

I have a module, which `@Provides` `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
@Module
class DateModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun dateFormat(): SimpleDateFormat {
        return SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US)
    }
}
```

and a Dagger component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(MyAppModule::class, DateModule::class))
interface MyAppComponent {
  ...
}
```

Lastly my `Application`:

```
open class MyApplication : Application() {
    private lateinit var myAppComponent: MyAppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        myAppComponent = createGraph()
    }

    open fun createGraph(): MyAppComponent {
        return DaggerMyAppComponent.builder().myAppModule(MyAppModule(this)).build()
    }

    fun getAppComponent(): MyAppComponent {
        return myAppComponent
    }

}
```

Now, I'm trying to `@Inject` `DateHelper` into my `Fragment`:

```
class CoffeeNoteFragment : Fragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Inject lateinit var dateHelper: DateHelper
    ...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        (activity.application as MyApplication).getAppComponent().inject(this)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting compile-time error

```
error: [com.example.mateusz.coffeenotes.application.MyAppComponent.inject(com.example.mateusz.coffeenotes.CoffeeNoteFragment)] java.text.SimpleDateFormat cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
  java.text.SimpleDateFormat is injected at
      com.example.mateusz.coffeenotes.database.DateHelper.<init>(arg0)
  com.example.mateusz.coffeenotes.database.DateHelper is injected at
      com.example.mateusz.coffeenotes.CoffeeNoteFragment.dateHelper
  com.example.mateusz.coffeenotes.CoffeeNoteFragment is injected at
      com.example.mateusz.coffeenotes.application.MyAppComponent.inject(arg0)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, since I'm `@Providing` the `SimpleDateFormat`. Obviously I cannot add `@Inject` constructor, since I don't own the `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Any help what I'm missing?

Comment: This looks fine to me, did you maybe mix in any `@Qualifier`, e.g. `@Named()` or something?

Comment: I managed to fix the issue. See my post below. I didn't provide enough information to notice the actual problem, but I didn't realize the error was coming from another component, because the error message pointed to MyAppComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved the problem**

I didn't realize the problem occurred from a different component, which I use for testing.

I have a `TestComponent` in `src/debug/java/...`, which provides mock implementations for my tests:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(TestModule::class))
interface TestComponent : MyAppComponent
```

Since this component extends `MyAppComponent`, I also have to provide bindings to it. Clearly I'm missing the `DateModule` here.
Changing to below **fixes the compilation error**:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(TestModule::class, DateModule::class))
interface TestComponent : MyAppComponent
```

I was mislead by the compile error message, which stated that `MyAppComponent` is missing the binding, whereas the actual problem lies within `TestComponent`.

Is my reasoning correct, that the actual error message should refer to `TestComponent`?